# How to solve equations involving multivalued functions in complex domain?

Tags: multivalued-functions

Does this equation have a solution in the complex domain?

$$
\sqrt{x+3} = 3 + \sqrt{x}
$$

Squaring both sides gives $\sqrt{x}=-1$, which suggests the solution to be $x=1$. But:

1. How can the complex domain solution be a purely real number?
2. Does this have a link to the multivalued nature of the function ($\sqrt{x}$) in the complex domain?
3. What is the correct way to deal with such equations involving multivalued functions in the complex domain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you write $\sqrt{z}$ for a complex number $z$, you need to specify what "branch" you are using. Otherwise, you are interpreting your equality in the equation as a set identity.

Comment: Where is this equation from? Do you make it up? Or is it from some exercise? That sort of information allows a more appropriate way to write an answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. Can you refer me to some detailed resource? I am not an expert in complex analysis.

Comment: Indeed, I confronted it on the web, someone asked about it in a math help page.

Comment: "which suggests the solution to be $x=1$". Why? This is incorrect.

Comment: What "detailed resource" are you looking for? You may begin with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers

Comment: Don't we have that by squaring both sides?

Comment: I mean some resource to read about the "branch" you mentioned above.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number

Comment: OK, I will read the wiki page. But, why can't we say that sqrt(x) = -1 suggests that x = 1? I didn't get this point. Could you explain?

Comment: In complex analysis, square root is a multivalued function: the square roots of $1$ are $-1$ and $1$.  So $\sqrt{1+3} = 3 + \sqrt{1}$ is correct in the sense that there are values of the square roots that make this true.  It just looks strange because we usually think of the square root of a positive real as the positive square root of that real, not the negative one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Then, x = 1 is a correct solution?